# Using repo sync for building android GPL-compliant?

Tags: android, synchronization, repo

the android sourcecode is pulled with repo sync, but as it consists of many repos, I can't think of a way how to create an exact same binary without kind of "exporting" the current state in a list with the repos with the last synced commit. But this is needed for it being GPL-compliant.

Or, as only the Linux-kernel is under GPL, ain't that needed?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: why this "exact the same binary" constraint? It is really hard to get the exact same binary even when the project is not distributed in different repos as you get things like time-stamps in there all the time anyway ..

Comment: @ligi It’s not the matter of ‘exact the same binary’, actually, but of ‘correspondent source’, i. e. that exact source code, from which that exact binary had been build once.

Comment: And, FWIW, Linux® is not the *only* part of Android covered by GNU GPL; for example, Bluez (`bluetoothd`) and Busybox are too.

Comment: @ligi afaik you need to prove that the binaries that you provide can be reproduced. Thus one needed all last synced commits.

Comment: @Dmitry Busybox is a part of Android? I thought that you needed to install it by youself? Anyway, that doesn't change my question ;-)

Comment: @LeonardK Yes, indeed, I’ve just googled and found a lot of instructions on how to install busybox on Android. Perhaps, it is a part of Android distributions that was pre-installed on computers I bought in recent years, not the ‘vanilla’ distribution. (And I just do remember how it was in times of HTC G1).